# why am i getting Exception for the following simple code snipped?

Tags: java, collections

I am getting exception when i try to display this linked list after using addFirst() and addLast() methods.

```
import java.util.List;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class File1 {

    public static void main(String ...args){

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(30);       
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext())
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");

        list.add(1,600);        
        System.out.println(list);       
        list.remove(1);
        System.out.println(list);

        System.out.println("now using linked list specific 2 methods...");

        list.addFirst(901);
        list.addLast(902);

            while(iterator.hasNext())   
            System.out.print(iterator.next()+" ");
             //this line throws Exception:

     } //end of main()
} //end of class
```

Comment: What exception? At what line?

Answer (score 1):

Running the code I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Quoting the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The 2nd `while` loop is using the iterator from the 1st `while` loop, and the list has been "structurally modified". Even if you didn't get this error, the 2nd loop wouldn't work, because the iterator is already at-end.

Add the following before the 2nd loop: `iterator = list.iterator();`
Or better yet use a `for` loop: `for (Integer value : list)`
Or even better, just print the list like you do after `add` and `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Create new iterator before second whike loop and print it.
Eg:
       Iterator iterator1 = list.iterator();

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(30);       
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");

    list.add(1,600);        
    System.out.println(list);       
    list.remove(1);
    System.out.println(list);

    System.out.println("now using linked list specific 2 methods...");

    list.addFirst(901);
    list.addLast(902);
    Iterator<Integer> iterator1 = list.iterator();
     while(iterator1.hasNext())   
     System.out.print(iterator1.next()+" ");
         //this line throws Exception:
```